# why XMLDocument AppendChild() adds "amp" to a xml node string value?

Tags: c#, .net, xmldocument, ampersand, appendchild

i have a URL string that i want to insert to an XMLDocument - XmlElement Node:

"http://xx.xxx.xxx.xx4:7000/SomeURL/Some/?Locale=asaf&;Portal=how"

when write this code :

```
XmlElement NodeElement = xmlDoc.CreateElement(nodeToCreate);
NodeElement.InnerText = propInfo.GetValue(requestData,null).ToString();
additionalParamsNode.AppendChild(NodeElement);
```

The Text in the 'NodeElement.InnerText' looks fine, but when i do the appendChild()
an "&amp" is written inside the XMLElement additionalParamsNode.
its like the XMLElement takes the InnerXML , not the InnerText of the NodeElement.

i dont want to write the string with "amp" to the XML cause the link wont work.

how do i appendChild without changing "&" to "&amp"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm remembering correctly, &'s are one of the illegal characters in XML.  That's why it is turned into &amp (the html equivalent of &).

You should be able to wrap the data in CDATA tags.

```
<![CDATA[http://xx.xxx.xxx.xx4:7000/SomeURL/Some/?Locale=asaf&;Portal=how]]>
```

You might have to parse out the CDATA tags when you are done though.

Comment: it doesn't help, i do : NodeElement.InnerText = "![CDATA[" + propInfo.GetValue(requestData,null).ToString() + "]]"; and still i get in the innerXML &amp instead of &.

Comment: You must have the starting < and ending > around the tag. NodeElement.InnerText = "<![CDATA[" + propInfo.GetValue(requestData,null).ToString() + "]]>";

Comment: And maybe set the InnerXml property instead of InnerText, to succesfully add the CDATA section instead of a plain escaped text.